# ksh validating string with logical OR

Tags: shell, ksh

I am writing a script in ksh which needs to check a variable is set to one of the two accepted values. I have got the following code but when I enter a valid value e.g. "C" I get the error message (Not a valid value):

```
if  [[ "$Mode" != "C" ]] || [[ "$Mode" != "M" ]] 
then

   echo ""
   echo "*Not a valid value*"

   exit 2;

fi
```

I am not sure why it is failing on the string comparison, I have tried varations on syntax but still not getting anywhere, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ! [[  "$Mode" == "C" || "$Mode" == "M" ]] ; then
   echo ""
   echo "*Not a valid value*"
   exit 2;
fi
```

I think this is the easier way to test multiple values. I like to think of it 'if Mode is NOT in the list of C, or M, or ....; then ....' I see beginners post code like yours (and I did it myself when I was a beginner), because then your mental model is 'if Mode is NOT C OR Mode is NOT M then ...', but you you really need the 'AND' instead (as illustrated by jlliagre).

I hope this helps.

Comment: @amer : Thanks, I've added some comments. Good luck.

Comment: nice way of describing the logical OR vs AND

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is flawed.

```
if  [[ "$Mode" != "C" ]] && [[ "$Mode" != "M" ]] 
then

   echo ""
   echo "*Not a valid value*"

   exit 2;

fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Years later...

For those who may follow, the *reason* amer's logic is flawed is, $Mode is *always* either not "C" OR not "M", because even a value like "C" is not "M", which makes the 2nd condition true.

Here are 2 one-liner alternatives:

```
[[ $Mode != "C" && $Mode != "M" ]] && echo -e "\n*Not a valid value*" && exit 2
```

This bash alterative allows for easy and concise adding of more valid values:

```
[[ `echo $Mode | egrep "C|M"` ]] || echo -e "\n*Not a valid value*" && exit 2
```

Why is everyone writing "$Mode" instead of just $Mode?  Try it before you answer, please.

Comment: Good explanation in sentence 2. But your second alternative (which works in ksh too) has the negative that you are using 3 processes `echo`,`egrep`, and the subshell created for `cmd-substitution` to perform a comparison that the shell does "for free";-). An alternate using your idea of (quasi)reg-ex matching can be had with `case "$Mode" in C|M ) : correct_option_received ;; * ) echo "$Mode not a valid value for Mode, expected C or M" ;; esac`. The `:` is a null operator for the shell so this code will only "throw an error" if there is bad input. I included `correct_opt_recd` as self-doc ....

Comment: Also, we use dbl-quotes around variables as a defensive programming technique. What happens to your first code, if `Mode="A String WIth Spaces"`? Try it ;-) . Good luck to all.

Comment: `$ Mode="A String WIth Spaces"; [[ $Mode != C && $Mode != M ]] && echo Invalid || echo Valid
Invalid
###############$ echo ${.sh.version}
Version JM 93t+ 2010-05-24`  ;-)

Comment: Good point re "case", @shellter. However, I _have_ tried my code in ksh & bash and it works with spaces in $Mode. For example: `Mode="A String WIth Spaces"; [[ $Mode != C && $Mode != M ]] && echo Invalid || echo Valid` Output is "Invalid". What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Thank you for testing my code on your system @shellter. It looks as if both of us get "Invalid" as the output when `Mode="A String WIth Spaces"`, which is what we want. Please explain how the double quotes around $Mode are a defensive programming technique in the case of my code.

Comment: Ha, you're right (in this case!). Somehow I had just read somewhere else today (but not is this thread apparently) how `[[ .... ]]` "does  the right thing" and doen't require quoting of variables. I never knew that. For me, I need consistency in use, so I will waste 2 extra chars per `[[ ... ]]` enclosed variable reference, so I have the habit of protecting against the normal problems of unquoted variables, but yep, you are right on this one! Good luck to all!

Comment: In `ksh` debugging mode (at least) you can see it happen `Mode="A String WIth Spaces"; [[ $Mode != C ]] && false || true ; echo $? ### 1 >Mode='A String WIth Spaces'
### 1 >[[ 'A String WIth Spaces' != C ]]
### 1 >false
### 1 >true
### 1 >echo 0
### 0` where `###` is a linefeed char. Note that inside the `[[` test, the value of `$Mode` has been automatically "quoted" by the shell. (The single quotes are not really in the code, just that is the way the shell has parsed the statement)). Thanks for making me dig deeper into this, learned something new!

Comment: Glad to be of service, @shelter, but does this mean that when I said "Try it before you answer, please", instead of doing that, you decided to ask me to "Try it ;-)"?  If so, please save everyone time and try it yourself first in future.  I already had tried this exact thing...for years.

As far as I know, the option to lose the double quotes came in with the option to use `[[...]]` instead of `[...]`. So you use 2 extra bytes for the brackets, but save 2 or more for the quotes, depending on the number of conditions you have inside them.